# Проверка существования option с заданным value

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">Цифра 1</option>
    <option value="3">Цифра 3</option>
    <option value="7">Цифра 7</option>
</select>
```

Как определить, существует ли `option` со значением, допустим, `4`? То есть нужно определить, существует ли это значение: `<option value="4">Цифра 4</option>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И  более многословно, без jQuery:

```
function hasOption(testedValue){ // testedValue - значение которое мы проверяем
    var select = document.getElementById('select'), // Наш select
        options = select.options;  // Объект, содержащий его опции

    for(var i = 0; i< options.length; i++){// Просто перебираем каждую опцию и проверяем
        if(options[i].value == testedValue){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('#select > option[value=4]').length) {
  alert('Существует');
}
```

Comment: С минимальным изменением можно это же сделать без jQuery для IE9+.

Answer (score 2):

Обращаю внимание, что значение должно быть заключено в кавычки (неважно, двойные или одинарные), иначе селектор будет некорректным.

```js
function test4() {
  return document.querySelector("#smth option[value='4']") !== null;
}

function test2() {
  return document.querySelector("#smth option[value='2']") !== null;
}
```

```html
<select id=smth>
  <option value=1>First
  <option value=4>Forth
</select>

<button onclick=alert(test4())>Yes</button>
<button onclick=alert(test2())>No</button>
```